# How to compare two tangents?

Tags: lua, trigonometry

How to compare two tangents? The problem is that atan2 returns sometimes pretty different results by pretty same angles.

```
local t1 = math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)
local t2 = math.atan2(y3-y2, x3-x2)
if t2-t1 < -math.pi/2 then
    print (t1, t2, t2-t1+2*math.pi)
elseif t2-t1 > math.pi/2 then
    print (t1, t2, t2-t1-2*math.pi)
else
    print (t1, t2, t2-t1)
end
```

maybe correction:

```
local t3 = t2-t1 < -math.pi/2 and 2*math.pi or t2-t1 > math.pi/2 and -2*math.pi or 0
print (t1, t2, t2-t1+t3)
```

Comment: `atan2 returns sometimes pretty different results` - Please show an example of such different results.

Comment: @egor-skriptunoff
t1, t2 and the difference:

       2.7690383951349 3.0448086084823 0.27577021334739;

       3.0448086084823 -2.9889433251945 -6.0337519336768;

       -2.9889433251945 -2.488166312409 0.5007770127855;

Comment: Why do you think that these different results correspond to `pretty same angles`?  Show their angles.

Comment: dy and dx? t1 and t2 are angles from atan2 function.

Comment: What are the values of dx and dy?  In your example dx values are different: `x2-x1` and `x3-x2`.  What are their exact values?